# How can I get an image's height in proportion to container's width?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Google Maps API to generate a map for a mobile application. As you will see, I can generate the width for the code no problem. I simply get the width of the container and subtract total padding. However, I now need to create a suitable height for the image. At the moment I have just entered 200 (because it looks right), but on other devices the width will be different. Is there a piece of code I can use to automatically generate the height and keep it in proportion to the width?

Thanks

```
var width = $(this).width();

document.write('<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
center=55.919070, -5.306156&amp;zoom=15&amp;size=' + (width - 30) +
'x200&amp;markers=55.919070, -5.306156&amp;sensor=false" width="' +
(width - 30) + '" height="200">');
```

Comment: Have you tried [$(this).height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)? Also, the padding is included as part of width() - as it is the *computed* height.

Comment: @LeonardChallis Hi, I should have said, the height of the container is much larger than the width. I don't want the image to fill the container, just an amount that keeps the image in proportion to its width.

Comment: What is the proportion?

Comment: @LeonardChallis Let's say a ratio of 16:9?? I'm not sure how to calculate it.

Comment: `height = (width/16)*9;`

Comment: @LeonardChallis Thanks man! Wrap that in Math.round and post as an answer so I can select it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work out a ratio (for instance 16:9) you can do the following calculation:

```
height = Math.round((width/16)*9);
```

Comment: Pleasure :) Nice idea for a 16:9 Google map ;)